# What is the Purpose of the DestinationAddress field in the MassTransit Envelope?

Tags: masstransit

When sending a message, MassTransit wraps that payload with an envelope which has a field called `destinationAddress`. What purpose does this field have?

I found this because I have a number of C# microservices communicating with some node and java based services - so I've been using the minimum payload defined here:
http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/interoperability.html

I've had no problem integrating the two services together I was just wondering what the point was of having the `destinationAddress` as part of the message itself? Is it just a belts and braces kind of thing to make sure messages don't go on the wrong queue by mistake?

I would have thought that all of this information can be derived since it is literally just built up of a) the message bus host and b) the queue name used when actually sending the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transports have a variety of ways to delivering messages. For instance, publishing a message to a topic would set the destination address to (URI of topic) but it may be delivered to a queue (via a subscription, forwarded by the transport) with a different address. In this case, the envelope has the original destinationAddress, whereas the queue would have a different address.

There are also cases where messages may be scheduled, redelivered, faulted, etc., and having that information helps in troubleshooting production systems in cases where the original destination may not be known otherwise.

So, yeah, in the simplest case it seems superfluous, however, it comes in useful down the road when trying to figure out why something doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful :) Makes total sense too!